# Instructing Macports to download, but not install, dependencies for a port

Tags: macports

I am sitting here in an airport, came up with something that I'd like to try, but I won't have time to `sudo port install` if macports downloads-compiles-downloads-compiles. If it downloaded everything, however, then I can have it compile on the plane.

How can I cache a port's dependencies but compile and install later?

Comment: This should work: sudo port fetch {packagename}; sudo port fetch depof:{packagename}

Comment: `depof:` only lists direct dependencies of packagename, not dependencies of the dependencies themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use

`sudo port fetch \( {packagename} or rdepof:{packagename} \) and not installed`

`rdepof:` recursively lists all dependencies of your package (including the dependencies of the dependencies themselves)

`and not installed` excludes all packages you have already installed.