# Macports: downloading all outdated ports and dependencies without installing them

Tags: download, installation, macports, macos-sierra

I'd like to download all outdated ports and their dependencies, but not install them. In essence, I'd like to perform `port upgrade outdated` in a *download everything* step and an *install everything* step.

This is very similar to the question asked here:

[Downloading MacPorts dependencies without installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755274/downloading-macports-dependencies-without-installing)

The difference between my question and that question is that the answer for that question works for a specified set of ports. My initial attempt was to run `port fetch rdepsof:outdated`, but MacPorts didn't like that. How could that answer be *generalized* to download everything that would need to be downloaded?

(Also, would I want to tag on `and not installed` at the end, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333298/instructing-macports-to-download-but-not-install-dependencies-for-a-port)?

Comment: Perhaps @SethDifley would know?

Comment: For upgrades you usually don't need to rebuild dependencies, so you shouldn't need the source for the dependencies. In this case, `sudo port fetch outdated` should work. If you add `and not installed`, nothing will be fetched, because by definition, you have all outdated ports installed.